# what is transaction management in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

What is transaction management in hibernate?

in my hibernate application one-to-many mapping is there.

Eg : `Student` table is mapped with `Subjects` table.

When I am adding a `Student` object at that time `Subjects` table also adding some entry.

While any error occurs in `Subjects` table insertion I want automatically delete the `Student` table entry.

Is it possible through transaction management? Else how is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you've described is exactly what transactions are for. The idea is that you group database operations into a single transaction and either they're all successful or they  all fail. This way your database cannot end up in an intermediate and invalid state.

Transaction management is a vast and often quite complex area and the way in which you configure it depends on your specific application setup.

Since you're only mentioned Hibernate I would recommend that you start by reading [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html) chapter of the documentation. If you are using Spring to demarcate transaction boundaries I would recommend you read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) section of their documentation.

It is worth noting that you cannot send SQL to your database outside of a transaction. There is discussion around this [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode).

Comment: page is not found for the first link